# Why does the child process executing uniq -d not print duplicates passed by pipe over stdin?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, uniq

I am currently writing a program which creates a child process using fork(). This child process shall execute the shell command "uniq" with the option "-d" so it reads from stdin. After the execute command I want to send strings as stdin over a pipe for the "uniq" program. So after I send the same string behind each other the string should be printed on stdout (see `uniq` man page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq). But nothing is printed.

Here is my code so far:

```
void execute_uniq_process()
{
    //create pipe
    int pipefd[2];
    if(pipe(pipefd)<0)
    {
        //error handling
    }

    //create argv for command:
    char *argv[] = {"uniq","-d",(char *)0};

    //create child process
    pid_t pid = fork();
    int status;

    switch(pid)
    {
        case -1:
        //error handling
        break;

        case 0:
            //child process
            //close writing end in pipe
            close(pipefd[1]);

            //duplicate stdin
            dup2(pipefd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
            close(pipefd[0]);

            execvp("uniq",argv);
            exit(errno);
        break;

        default:
            //parent process
            //close reading end in pipe
            close(pipefd[0]);

            //write all commands to pipe
            write(pipefd[1],"test1",5);
            write(pipefd[1],"test1",5);
            write(pipefd[1],"test2",5);
            //edited:
            close(pipefd[1]);

            //waits till child is finished
            wait(&status);

            if(WEXITSTATUS(status) != EXIT_SUCCESS)
            {
                //error handling
            }
        break;
    } 
}
```

So I would expect that there is printed "test1" in the shell. I also wonder how to terminate the `uniq` process cleanly. I think there could probably be a issue with write, so that I have to simulate an "enter" after every string I write in the pipe.

Comment: You have to close the pipe before waiting for `uniq` to finish, because it won't know it's got EOF until you close the pipe. And you've not written even one line to the standard input of `uniq`.  The `write()` system call writes what you tell it to write, and certainly doesn't add any newlines of its own volition.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post and closed the pipe before i wait for the uniq - process. Now it terminates. But i don't understand till now why nothing is written to stdin of uniq. The read end of the child was directed to stdin. And the parent writes in the pipe. Sorry for the question i am new to this topic.

Comment: You haven't written a whole line of input to `uniq`; there are no newlines in what you write, so there is no duplication (`uniq` sees `test1test1test2` without a newline).  See my answer.

Comment: Now it works, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to close the pipe before waiting for `uniq` to finish, because it won't know it's got EOF until you close the pipe. And you've not written even one line to the standard input of `uniq` because there isn't a newline in the data that was written.  The `write()` system call writes only what you tell it to write; it certainly doesn't add any newlines of its own volition.

Those changes, and sundry trivia, lead to:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pipefd[2];
    if (pipe(pipefd) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create pipe\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *argv[] = {"uniq", "-d", (char *)0};

    pid_t pid = fork();

    switch (pid)
    {
    case -1:
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fork\n");
        return 1;

    case 0:
        close(pipefd[1]);
        dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to exec %s\n", argv[0]);
        exit(errno);

    default:
        close(pipefd[0]);
        write(pipefd[1], "test1\n", 6);
        write(pipefd[1], "test1\n", 6);
        write(pipefd[1], "test2\n", 6);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        int status;
        int corpse = wait(&status);

        if (WEXITSTATUS(status) != EXIT_SUCCESS)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Child (%s) exited (PID %d, status 0x%.4X)\n", argv[0], corpse, status);
        }
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs `test1` when it is run.